# ¿Es correcto en algún caso decir "dar de mí" en lugar de "dar de sí"?

Tags: gramática, locuciones, persona-gramatical

Leyendo una entrevista a Julio Anguita me encontré con la frase:

> Dos años antes de mis problemas cardiovasculares reuní a mis colaboradores más cercanos en una cena. Les planteé que **yo ya había dado de sí** todo lo que podía dar.
>
> <sub>[Julio Anguita: "Los de Cataluña son presos políticos; los de Venezuela, presos comunes"](https://www.elespanol.com/opinion/20180930/julio-anguita-cataluna-presos-politicos-venezuela-comunes/341467142_0.html). El Español, 30 septiembre 2018</sub>

Me picó la curiosidad que dijera *yo ya he dado de sí* y no *he dado de mí*. Efectivamente la locución es *dar de sí*:

> [**sí**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XmOP8Ia%7CXmQKxT2).
>   de sí.
>   1. loc. adv. [**de suyo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YqlzSAz).
>
> > **de suyo**.
> >     1. loc. adv. Naturalmente, propiamente o sin sugestión ni ayuda ajena.

Pero me pregunto: ¿sería correcto, aunque sea originariamente (esto es, antes de que la locución lo convirtiera en un todo), crear esta construcción haciendo coincidir la persona con el objeto a que representa?

Comment: La RAE dice que "No es recomendable el uso de la forma reflexiva sí para referirse a una primera o una segunda persona, tanto del singular como del plural".

Comment: @enxaneta buen descubrimiento. Veo que aparece en el DPD de [_sí_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=OPRQrNgR6D6MJDLkBh), donde se añade que _ha de tenerse en cuenta que el uso de estas locuciones no se da con normalidad en las personas de plural_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La acepción que equipara «de sí» a «de suyo» no es la que se aplica en este caso. Por el contexto se entiende que Anguita está hablando de dar de sí mismo, es decir, de su fuerza, su voluntad, etc., antes empleadas en participar en contiendas electorales. No habla de dar algo (¿qué cosa?) "por sí mismo, sin ayuda ni sugestión". Más bien parecería que todo lo contrario, hasta el punto de que la reunión que menciona parece una oportunidad para excusarse ante quienes esperan algo más de él.

En mi opinión Anguita está simplemente empleando mal la frase, que debería ser «había dado de **mí**». Él o quien transcribe la entrevista.

Entiendo que más que «dar de sí» la expresión debería aparecer como «dar de uno (mismo)», pero en el DLE no hay una acepción específica. Sería un uso paralelo al de «dar (algo) del propio bolsillo (de uno)».

Comment: Interesante, muchas gracias. La verdad es que ambos me suenan raro (_yo doy de sí_ / _yo doy de mí_), pero se agradece saber cuál de ellos es el correcto :) Como indicó enxaneta en los comentarios a la pregunta, el [artículo de _sí_ del DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=OPRQrNgR6D6MJDLkBh) indica que _ha de tenerse en cuenta que el uso de estas locuciones no se da con normalidad en las personas de plural_.

Comment: Muy interesante lo que dice el DPD, especialmente cómo *de por sí* suele ser utilizado como frase fija en vez de cambiar *sí* por la persona gramatical que corresponda. Creo haber cometido ese error más de una vez.